# Calling an application from a server

Tags: c#, .net

I have an (console, .NET 3.5, C#) application that I'm trying to call from a Windows Server (2003, with .NET 3.5) from a system (Windows server 2003 with .NET 2.0) via a scheduler (the scheduler app is called 24x7, it's a script based scheduler, in this case, it calls the executable strait up, no parameters, etc).
The issue is when it tries to call it, it sees it as a file and tries to "download" it. I've tried running the app from the command prompt, only to get the same results. I've tried everything I can think of, even writing a launchpad type application and using that to call the app, but I get the same results every time.

Am I missing something? Is there a security flag or something I've overlooked? I've never seen this before.

Edit: Sorry, forgot to mention that the app is being called via full UNC path (\myserver\myfolder\myapp.exe)

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't understood the question: you are trying to *execute* an application from Windows Server 2003 through a scheduler? Which scheduler is it, and what command?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to execute an application from Windows server. The scheduler is called 24x7, the command it runs is simply the UNC path to the application (\\myserver\myfolder\myapp.exe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hmm.... how exactly are you "calling" this application? via SMB? (i.e. by executing the command `\\myserver\sharepath\foo.exe` from a command line)

If so, your application doesn't run with the same permissions and you can run into code access issues, but that'll come as an error message, rather than a file download.

The fact that you're getting a file download leads me to believe that you're trying to "run" the console application over http, but I don't have enough information to know for sure, hence my question.

Comment: I am calling the app via UNC pathing, which is how I have many other apps running. The security permissions (should be) set correctly, although it seems like I am missing something.

Comment: So you've done this successfully with other programs before? Then what's changed? What's different about this program specifically? Or perhaps the issue is with the scheduling script call itself.

Comment: Well the issue still occurs when I run a manual call from a command prompt. No matter what I try (calling the program directly, or via a launchpad style app) it always comes up with the "download" dialog.

There is nothing different, except the servers. (I work on several servers, all of which SHOULD have identical configurations). My other apps all run from the same style command, except this one.

Comment: What happens if you run the application from your local machine rather than over the network?

Comment: Running from the local machine works perfectly fine.
I'm so baffled, it's incredibly frustrating!!

Comment: Hmm... I can understand that. What does the program *do*? Does it do file manipulation? Database data processing?

Comment: The app is pretty simple, it pulls data out of a database, formats it in a certain spec and spits it out into various text files.

Comment: Could the "download dialog" you receive be caused by the program itself? Could it be using, say, FileDialog?

Comment: FileDialog? As in the Windows Forms object? It's a console app, which doesnt use any of the forms stuff. The files it spits out are predetermined filenames with the date appended to them (ie. file_a_20100303.txt file_b_20100303.txt, etc)

Comment: Sorry, just grasping for straws.

Comment: Yeah, me too at this point.
Thanks anyway, for your help!
I'm just going to force someones hand to upgrade the 2.0 server to 3.5, so I can just run it locally!